# Accessing Object information in Deno

Tags: properties, typeof, deno

When using Deno 0.42.0, I find it difficult to do any type of analysis of objects by using typeof or other inspection techniques I use in JavaScript.

For example:

```
const form = new FormData();
console.log(`typeof: ${ typeof form }`);
```

.. just returns `object`

Similarly, inspecting properties like:

```
const form = new FormData();
console.log(`props: ${ Object.getOwnPropertyNames(form) }`);
```

... returns nothing.

At least instanceof does work:

```
const form = new FormData();
console.log(`props: ${ form instanceof FormData }`);
```

... returns `true`

Is there a way in Deno to inspect objects in real time without first knowing what the object type is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works exactly like that on the browser too.

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) possible return values are:

- undefined
- object
- boolean
- number
- bigint
- string
- symbol
- function

So it's not possible for you to get another value.

---

Maybe what you want is `.constructor.name`

```
const form = new FormData();
console.log(`class: ${form.constructor.name}`); // FormData
console.log(`props: ${ form instanceof FormData }`); // true
```